# Git branching django

Tags: django, git, git-branch

I am looking to edit some of the documentation found on the django project. To do this I have forked, and cloned to my local machine a copy of the django repository on github.

The issue I am facing is that I cannot access the 1.3.X branch, make changes, the commit / push the changes back to git hub.

When trying to access django branch remotes/origin/1.3.X i get a warning about a detached head.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Fork that repository on GitHub. Clone your fork or add this as another remote. Make a branch off of this branch. Make your changes, commit them and then push your branch up to your forked repo. Now make a pull request of your branch.